# better way to position elements in css?

Tags: html, css

hello so im new to html and CSS, I'm using this way to move around elements.. is this the right way to move elements? is there an easier way? because I moved them like 100 times to get a perfect way.. please don't judge mt class naming, its just for testing xd..
I'm really struggling of moving around elements in gernal, so I'm doing multiple examples to understand it more. thanks in advance!
*:
in left/in right means like between them lol..

HTML:

```
    <footer>
    <h1 class="foot">left</h1>
    <h1 class="foot f">in left</h1>
    <h1 class="foot ff">right</h1>
    <h1 class="foot fff">in right</h1>
    <h1 class="foot ffff">middle</h1>
 </footer>
```

CSS:

```
.f{
    position: absolute;
    left: 250px;
    
}
.ff{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
}

.fff{
    position: absolute;
    right: 250px;
}
.ffff{
    position: absolute;
    right: 700px;
}

.foot{
    display: inline;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
}
footer{
    height: 100px;
    padding: 25px;
    
    background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to get to know flexbox.
It will allow you to position your elements in many different ways and for it to stay responsive. The problem with using pixels for positioning is that if you were to make your screen smaller, they will potentially go off screen or if you made the screen larger if would not take the full screen.

https://flexboxfroggy.com/ is a pretty cool way to learn flex.

*Example of horizontally aligning content on the x axis.*

```
<footer style="display: flex; justify-content: center">
    <h1 class="foot">left</h1>
    <h1 class="foot">in left</h1>
    ...
</footer>
```

Comment: thanks for the source, will look into that, do devs mostly use flex/flexbox to position items?

Comment: @jacobhanson I mostly use flex/flexbox, its an amazing tool and the flexbox froggy resource that has been shared is how I got comfortable with it!

Comment: yes @jacobhanson it is common practice to use flexbox for grid systems. However, once starting out, it can become incredibly tempting to just use flex everywhere. However, with time, you'll learn which elements need to be flex elements and which do not. Having flex elements do create an overhead for the browser as it does require the browser to do some calculations.

Comment: I recommend flex / flexbox, the code is less complex, and you save a lot of time for responsive design.

Answer (score 0):

When using position absolute, a nice trick I use to avoid having to update the code hundreds of times trying to get the element into the perfect position is to set it once as a guess then go into chromes dev inspector. from inside the dev inspector, find the element that you are trying to position and look for the css styles that you applied. Once you've located the style in the inspector, you can click and drag on the `px` value and it will move the element on the page in real time.

One thing to note about `position: absolute;` is that it doesn't behave very nicely in responsive layouts. so your mobile layout will likely need tweaking to get things looking good!

Comment: great trick , will try it now! also what do you think its best to use to position elements? like for web and mob versions?

Comment: I've been using `tailwind css` lately, it's a css framework similar to `bootstrap` but I find that it excels at making designs responsive. The css properties that I use are mostly `flex` and `grid` these days, but things like `bootstraps` `col` and `row` systems are great for layouts

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways to move elements around in CSS but the main ones that are considered best practice are to use either: Grid or Flexbox. I recommend you watch a few tutorials on Flexbox and Grid that will help you a lot.

Comment: thank you! will definitely look it up on yt rn.